# iOS, Swift: How to save an array that contains custom objects so that I can be loaded for reuse?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, save

I have an array that contains objects that I've created. I would like the manager class to load this array from the disk so that I can continue appending to the array.

---HERE IS THE CLASS I WOULD LIKE TO MANAGE LOADING THE ARRAY

```
 class FoodManager{
    var foodList : [FoodItem]

    func addFood(name : String, carbs : Int, fat: Int, protein : Int) {
        let food = FoodItem(name: name, carbs: carbs, protein: protein,       fat: fat)
        foodList.append(food)
    }

    init(){
        foodList = [FoodItem]()
        //Here is where I would like to load the array to initialize foodList or if the file doesn't exist, create a new array

    }
}
```

-----HERE IS THE CLASS THAT IS IN THE ARRAY----

```
class FoodItem{
    let name: String
    let carbs: Int
    let protein: Int
    let fat: Int

    init(name: String, carbs: Int, protein: Int, fat: Int){
        self.name = name
        self.carbs = carbs
        self.protein = protein
        self.fat = fat
    }
}
```

I've found a lot of info on saving a class that has just primitive data types but have been having trouble finding examples where an array of user defined objects needs to be saved.

thanks!

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encoding_decoding_and_serialization

Answer (score 0):

This would be the implementation of your custom class if you want to save it for reuse.

```
class FoodItem: NSCoding {
    let name: String?
    let carbs: Int?
    let protein: Int?
    let fat: Int?

required init(name: String, carbs: Int, protein: Int, fat: Int){
    self.name = name
    self.carbs = carbs
    self.protein = protein
    self.fat = fat
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    aCoder.encode(carbs, forKey: "carbs")
    aCoder.encode(protein, forKey: "protein")
    aCoder.encode(fat, forKey: "fat")
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey : "name") as? String
    self.carbs = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey : "carbs") as? Int
    self.protein = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey : "protein") as? Int
    self.fat = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey : "fat") as? Int
}
}
```

For saving this class object into userdefaults you can use:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: YourObjectToSave)
                        userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "DummyName")
                        userDefaults.synchronize()
```

For getting the object back from userdefaults you can use:

```
let decoded  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "DummyName") as! NSData
let decodedClassObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded as Data) as! FoodItem
```

## EDIT:

## Saving array of FoodItems:

Lets say I have an array of FoodItems:

```
 let itemArray: [FoodItem] = [item1, item2, item3]
```

You can now use the same code to save this array as well:

```
 let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                    let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: YourObjectToSave)
                    userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "itemArray")
                    userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Now retrieve the array as:

```
let decoded  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "itemArray") as! NSData
let decodedClassObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded as Data) as! [FoodItem]
```

Comment: Do not use `UserDefaults` to save data.

Comment: I appreciate the the reply, but it still doesn't answer my question. I understand more or less how to save one object. What i would like to do is save an array that contains many FoodItem objects.

Comment: @nimak: I have added the code for saving an array of custom objects.

Comment: thanks for the replay @amrit sidhu. I ended up doing something similar.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use NSCoder class to save custom object array in your manager class.

Comment: From what ive researched with nscoder so far, the object in the array needs to extend? the NSCoder protocol? Would the manager class need to do this as well or does it just handle the loading and saving... thanks

Comment: I solved the problem using the NSCoder protocols. Thanks Sahil!